# Multi Line from Html Document

Tags: java, html, jlabel

hello so I am trying to show an update list in a label that has more then one line so i written out this code

```
    public void GetUpdates() throws Exception {
    URL website = new URL(Configration.UpdatesUrl);
    URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(  new InputStreamReader( connection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    String inputLine;
    String info = "";
    int startLine = 1;
    int endLine = 50;
    for (int i = 0; i < startLine; i++) { 
        info = in.readLine(); 
    }
    for (int i = startLine; i < endLine + 1; i++) {
        info = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(info);
    }
    UpdateText.setText(info);
    in.close();
}
```

But he issue is it only shows the last line now i know you can use html tags but i have the same issue still so basically is just reading the last line of the text here is the document if u want to see it  see it

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ids6aa9w0pifdbq/Christian%20Updates.txt?dl=1

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `info += in.readLine();` instead of just `info = in.readLine();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating `info` with the new value in every loop iteration, instead of appending the new data to `info`. So the code in the second loop should be like this (note the `+=`)

```
for (int i = startLine; i < endLine + 1; i++) {
    info += in.readLine();
    System.out.println(info);
}
```

You might also want to use `StringBuilder` for better performance

Answer (score 0):

You're only getting the last line because you are setting the text `UpdateText.setText(info);`  after you have iterated through all of your lines. You should use `info += in.readLine();` to get the entire file in one string. Or you could use the string builder that doesnt seem to do anything